About pump.fun token distribution
According to pump.fun, After a token reach a marketcap of 69k$, 12k$ will be deposit to raydium to provide liquidity and they will lock every trading activity in that token on pump.fun . So, my question is, where is other 57k$ in the marketcap? What pump.fun do with these money ?

Reaching a market cap of $69k doesn't necessarily mean there is $69k in liquidity. Market cap is a representation of the total value of all tokens in circulation, calculated as:
Market Cap = Current Price x Circulating Supply
In this case, the $12k deposited into Raydium provides the initial liquidity, which helps determine the token's price. The market cap reflects the token price multiplied by the circulating supply, not the total available liquidity. The remaining $57k in market cap represents the value of the token based on its current price, but not all of it is immediately accessible as liquidity.
